# Connectify not working properly?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, connectify

I use connectify to create a wifi hotspot which I use in my Android device. But a problem occurs that the internet access stops after a minute or so in my Android device. I have to restart connectify so that it works fine again, but again I face the same problem in a minute or so.

Its not a problem with my device as it runs properly on other wifi networks.

Any solution to this??

Answer (score 0):

Use a portable small utility [mHotspot](http://mhotspot.com) instead of Connectify. Connectify does have such type of issues. So, mHotspot is my all time favorite when it comes to creating virtual hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and solved it by enabling, on connectify, local access to the device I wanted to transfer the files to.

Worked great after that.